# Check upload status from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a React-Express app where I need to select an image from the client, send it to the server, create a PDF with the image in it and then upload the PDF to a cloud service. I already done all that but I was wondering if it would be possible to send an upload status from the server to the client so that I can render a few alerts saying "I'm creating the PDF", then "I'm uploading your PDF" and finally "Your PDF has been uploaded".

Right now, I can only display two alerts on React, that are "I'm creating and uploading your PDF" and then, when the server sends the response, I render "Your PDF has been uploaded", and that's because I got only one route on Express that is managing the creation and the upload therefore just one response is being sent to React.

How can I do this? I was thinking about using sessions and multiple delayed requests to make this happen: the first one to send the file to the server, then two batches of infinite requests, the first to know when the PDF has been created (which the server will know based on a session parameter) and the second to know when the file has been uploaded. Would this be the right way or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Poll the server for updates using AJAX requests, basically "what's the status" in a loop until it completes (be careful with this as you could overload your server if you make too many requests too quickly.
2. Implement WebSockets to send updates to the client.  I'd suggest looking into socket.io (https://socket.io/) and working through their tutorials.

Comment: That's very useful, thank you! If I choose to use polling, what do you suggest I should use to get this status? Like sessions, cookies or something else?

Comment: I'd suggest you return some type of ID back when the image is submitted (GUID for instance) and use that GUID with the status checks.